# What is the default ports tree in FreeBSD 12.1? Easiest way to change it?

Tags: freebsd, bsd-ports

[Starting with a fresh install of FreeBSD-12.1-RELEASE](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports-using.html), when I run

```
# portsnap fetch 
# portsnap extract
```

does it extract the release branch, quarterly branch, HEAD or some other branch? Is there a config setting somewhere to change this or should I use subversion to track another ports tree?

I'm fine using subversion, so I don't need a run down on that. Just wondering what the default is and if there's a simpler config to tweak and avoid it. Also, I understand that pkg uses the quarterly branch by default, but I'm not finding similar information on about ports.

Answer (score 1):

The default ports tree is the current one. FreeBSD does not support older versions but they can be included as described below if you need an older port.

Quarterly branches are cut from the HEAD to build packages from them.

You can change which index you get and which categories by modifying `/etc/portsnap.conf` Details on how to do that are in `man portsnap.conf` and `man portsnap`

For example:

```
# List of INDEX files to build and the DESCRIBE file to use for each
INDEX INDEX-12 DESCRIBE.12
```

https://www.freebsd.org/ports/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the /etc/portsnap.conf file on a 12.1-RELEASE and and a 13-CURRENT machine show the same information except which INDEX and describe file to build. So it's the HEAD of the ports tree. I think only packages have a quarterly branch.